# How to Build a phonegap Application?

Tags: cordova

I have developed a phone gap application and i followed the steps to build the phone gap application which is given by build.phonegap.com . And i successfully  generated  the final output for all platforms. But this application is not working in symbian, windows,it always shows a blank screen, And it is working fine in android.

Comment: I guess you are doing copy/paste for all files from the www folder on android to the one on windows. You need to make sure NOT to copy cordova.js from the www folder. The cordova.js file is different for each OS. Make sure to use the cordova.js of windows mobile

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it yet, but I thought I've read, that you should reference the cordova.js in your index.html, but not include the actual JS file, since it will be added automatically during the build process.

So I'd say, just remove the cordova.js before building your app with build.phonegap.com and it should work.

Comment: This is absolutely correct, no need to keep the file in your archive, just reference it in the index file and PhoneGap Build includes it for you. However, I don't think this is why the OP's app isn't working correctly on those platforms.

Answer (score 0):

While in including the cordova only add the cordova.js.After that at time of building phonegap build will take care about which cordova should be added in the WWW directory OR 
U can use Cordova-1.5.0.js For reference use following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh975345.aspx 
for building the phonegap application for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I've used Phonegap Build many times, and without seeing the specific code to your application I cannot say exactly what is wrong with your app. Phonegap Build will automatically insert the Phonegap version you specify in your config.xml file... so I'm not sure the answers about what to include or not include in terms of cordova.js are going to yield much results.

My suggestion is to check out what features of Phonegap/Cordova you are using in your application. Phonegap Build may successfully build your application (package it into a binary/file used by app distributors), but that doesn't mean it actually works on the devices it is built for.

Here is fairly complete list of features that Phonegap supports for various devices: http://phonegap.com/about/feature/.

My guess is you're using something that is supported on Android that is not supported on Windows Phone or Symbian. That, or you are not entering the correct permissions in the config.xml. Take a look at https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml and find the "PhoneGap API Features" section. If some of you permissions are not set correctly in the  tag some apps may not work correctly on all devices.